# Как исправить ошыбку MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая проблема. OpenServer выдает ошибку MySQL server has gone away при том что я установил

```
wait_timeout=288000
max_allowed_packet = 10240M
```

Но даже с такими огромными значениями ошибка не пропала. Дело в том что я работаю с таблицей в которой около 147 млн строк.

Подскажите как еще можно решить данную проблему. Спасибо.

Запрос

```
SELECT LAT_LA_ID FROM tof_link_la_typ WHERE tof_link_la_typ.LAT_TYP_ID=:type_id
```

Ответ при использовании EXPLAIN

```
[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => tof_link_la_typ
[type] => ALL
[possible_keys] => 
[key] => 
[key_len] => 
[ref] => 
[rows] => 140794627
[Extra] => Using where
```

Таблица без primary key т.к. это линоквочная таблица, но я уже пробую просто достать данные из нее, т.к. думал что проблема в join

Comment: Как выполняете запрос? В консольном mysql-клиенте получается дождаться ответа? Сколько времени выполняется запрос?

Comment: @cheops, я выполняю запрос из php скрипта. Скрипт выполняется около 5 минут и тогда появляется ошыбка.

Comment: Выполните EXPLAIN для запроса, дополните отчетом этого оператора вопрос и если не сложно приведите сам запрос. Вероятно придется оптимизировать запрос, но для этого нужно выяснить по какому плану MySQL его выполняет.

Comment: @cheops, вот ответ при EXPLAIN          
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => tof_link_la_typ
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => 
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 140794627
            [Extra] => Using where

Comment: Запрос добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: Проиндексируйте пожалуйста поле LAT_TYP_ID, это должно привести к ускорению запроса.

Comment: @cheops, не могу т.к. поле не уникальное. Имею в виду значения.

Comment: индекс не обязательно должен быть уникальным, обычный не уникальный тоже здорово поможет.

Comment: @cheops, при попытке поставить индекс та же ошыбка что и при виполнении скрипта

Comment: Вам придется выйти за границы скриптов, ограниченных по времени и выполнять запросы в клиентах, где такого ограничения нет. Или снимать это ограничение в скрипте (в случае php set_time_limit(0)) - таблица слишком велика, индексация требует времени.

Comment: @cheops, подскажите что Вы имеете в виду под "клиентами"?

Comment: Например, консольную программу mysql, которая поставляется с каждым дистрибутивом MySQL. Она позволяет выполнять запросы в консоли или MySQL Workbeanch

Comment: @cheops, при добавлении индекса через консоль через некоторое время получаю ошыбку Lost connection to MySQL server during query